# Angular and spfx learning guide

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am getting started with spfx and i have no prior knowledge of angularjs/angular.

Recently i saw a blog post that says to use angular element to develop webpart.

Can you guys please guide me on how to really get into spfx development meaning should i learn typescript first then move to angular 6 then start spfx.

Is there anything more i need to learn like sass,office UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to start with react, instead of angular, for a few reasons:

- react is very well supported in SPFX
- react today (as of Sept, 2018) is the most popular library for building web interfaces (and mobile as well, which is a big thing). That means, that you will easily find a lot of samples, ready-to-use control and components over the internet or GitHub
- there are tons of examples on [github](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts) for SPFX, 90% of them react-based
- [office UI fabric](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components) was written in react
- there are [property pane controls](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/) and [reusable spfx controls](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/) in react
- angular element in SPFx is more like an experiment, without many docs, there might be a nightmare to solve all possible issues you might have during development

For the plan, I would suggest you start with react and Typescript, then go to SPFx and learn Office ui fabric as well.

Comment: If there any course series that i can use to learn react and spfx beside youtube and pluralsight courses. Sergei Sergeev

Comment: I really recommend [this one](https://www.udemy.com/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/) on react from udemy. I completed it some time ago and found it really helpful. They usually have discounts and the average price is about 10-15$. For SPFx there is only one comprehensive course from Andrew Connel - [Mastering SPFx](https://www.voitanos.io/p/course-master-sharepoint-framework), which is more expensive - around 300$

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start with SPFX(no javascript framework).

Then check out the examples at [GitHub samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples) (Only the ones starting with js-...)

Once you are confident with js examples, then start with [Basic Angular Example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-client-side-web-parts-with-angular-1-x)

Then, at last, the examples at [Github](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples)

If you are planning to use office ui fabric, then you should get started with react not angular.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply follow the SPFX Guidence here:

[Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Try to build the first SPFX Web Part with no JavaScript framework and then check SPFX Demos from GitHub:

[Code samples and developer content targeted towards SharePoint Framework client-side web parts.](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts)

After you are familiar with SPFX Web Part Process, then learn about Typerscript, Angular Js deeply, it will be better.

Comment: i did follow the Hello world tutorial but what to do next is what i want to know. If i learn angular which version we are talking here 1 or 5+ .

Comment: why angular and not react?

Comment: just my 20 cents. Don't invest time in learning Angular 1.x (aka Angularjs). That's an old version, has some performance issues. Today only React or Angular 5+ are valid in the market. And probably vuejs, which is a bit less popular.